# List of type class, adding values to a List <> of datatype CLASS

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, list, dynamic

I am retrieving 4 Fields from my database table. Now i want to add them to a dynamic list <>. How to add those into the list.
I tried this :

```
public class myclass
{
   public string StdDetails, StdAdderID;
   public DateTime StdAddedDate, StdAddedTime;
}

public void buttonClick()
{
    List<myclass> StdList = new List<myclass>();

    myclass mc = new myclass();

    OdbcCommand readStd = 
        new OdbcCommand("SELECT StdDetails, StdAddedDate," +
                        "StdAddedTime, StdAdderID" +
                        "FROM Students", Conn);

    OdbcDataReader readStdreader = 
        readStd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.SingleRow);

    while (readStdreader .Read())
    {
        mc.StdDetails = readStdreader.GetString(0);
        mc.StdDetails = readStdreader.GetString(3); 
        mc.StdDetails = readStdreader.GetDate(1);
        mc.StdDetails = readStdreader.GetDateTime(2);
        StdList.Add(mc);
    }
    MessageBox.Show(StdList[0].ToString());
}
```

In the message box the value isn't displayed? what to do.please help

//SORRY FOR THE TYPOS :

replace these 3 lines :

```
mc.StdDetails = readStdreader.GetString(3); 
        mc.StdDetails = readStdreader.GetDate(1);
        mc.StdDetails = readStdreader.GetDateTime(2);
```

with :

```
mc.StdAddedDate= readStdreader.GetString(3); 
                mc.StdAdderID= readStdreader.GetDate(1);
                mc.StdAddedTime= readStdreader.GetDateTime(2);
```

Comment: For one it looks like you are re-assigning all your database values to just the StdDetails property of 'myclass'. StdDetails will always be equal to readStdreader.GetDateTime(2) and the rest of the properties will be null.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're only creating a single *instance* of `myclass`, so your list will be full of references to the same object. You want this instead:

```
while (readStdreader.Read())
{
    myclass mc = new myclass();
    mc.StdDetails = readStdreader.GetString(0);
    mc.StdAdderID = readStdreader.GetString(3);
    mc.StdAddedDate= readStdreader.GetDate(1);
    mc.StdAddedTime = readStdreader.GetDateTime(2);
    StdList.Add(mc);
}
```

Note how I've changed the properties that are assigned, too - the code you posted attempts to assign to `StdDetails` repeatedly.

You also haven't overridden `ToString` in `myclass`, so calling `ToString()` isn't going to give you anything particularly useful.

Additionally:

- You should look into the .NET naming conventions; your naming is all over the shop at the moment. (What does `std` mean here? You've used it for almost everything...)
- Public fields are a really bad idea; use properties instead
- Use `using` statements to close readers, commands, connections etc in a reliable way.

Comment: @sqlchild: Where? If it's *after* the while loop, perhaps there weren't any rows?

Comment: @Jon: regarding your question what "Std" means in his code, my psychic powers say it's short for "student'. :)

Comment: @Sven: Yes, quite possibly. But that suggests that `myclass` should be renamed to `Student` and the prefixes should be removed :)

Comment: sir , its giving error, am having 10 rows in the database, then also? i have put the message box outside the while loop,IT INSERTS ONLY ONE ROW INTO THE LIST, WHEN I TRY TO ACCESS THE ROW 1 ,THEN IT GIVES INDEX ERROR.......THIS LINE WORKS:  MessageBox.Show(StdList[0].StdDetails.ToString() + "\n"
+ StdList[0].StdAddedDate.ToString()
                    + "\n" + StdList[0].StdAddedTime.ToString()
                  + "\n" + StdList[0].StdAdderID.ToString());------------it works only for 0 index, but if i put 1 IN PLACE OF ZERO , THEN it gives error

Comment: @sqlchild: Then it's only going through the loop once. Step through it in a debugger to work out what's going on.

Comment: @sqlchild: Start the program in the debugger, with a breakpoint just before the while loop, then step over it...

Comment: YES SIR, you are absolutely right, the while loop runs only once............why so sir?...what shall i do now????????????

Comment: ok sir, am using Visual studio 2005, so i pressed F5, now what do?

Comment: @sqlchild: I'm afraid I can't give you a detailed course in debugging in the comments here. Read some tutorials about debugging in Visual Studio, check that your data *really is* in the database, etc.

Comment: just a little help sir, after F5, i added a breakpoint, now what?

Comment: just a little help sir, after F5, i added a breakpoint, then i stepped over it. now?

Comment: @sqlchild: As I said before, read some tutorials about debugging in Visual Studio. This is *not* the appropriate place to teach you the details from scratch.

Answer (score 2):

It does not work that way.

First, you have to move `MyClass mc = new MyClass();` inside the `while`, because you must create a new instance every time and not change the existing one.

Second, calling `StdList[0].ToString();` will simply output the `MyClass` name, as you didn't provide an override for the `ToString()` method.

Third, in your `while` you're always using the `StdDetails` property, but I think this is a typo, as it wouldn't compile (you're assigning a String to a DateTime the third and fourth time, and the compiler doesn't like it).

Try with `StdList[0].StdDetails` instead of `StdList[0].ToString()` in the message box.

Answer (score 1):

There are two fundamental issues here:

1. You are reusing the same instance of `myclass` every time. That means that your list contains the same instance over and over, and since you update that instance every time the loop iterates, its value is that of the last value read from the DB. You need to do a `mc = new myclass()` inside your while loop.
2. Your `myclass` definition doesn't override `ToString()`. So calling `StdList[0].ToString()` at the end will just use the default `ToString()` implementation, which returns the type name, not anything meaningful.

Answer (score 1):

Two things. You are re-assigning values to only the StdDetails property of myclass, and you aren't accessing any particular property in the MessageBox. Need to do:

```
 while (readStdreader .Read())    
 {        
    myclass mc = new myclass(); 
    mc.StdDetails = readStdreader .GetString(0);        
    mc.StdAdderID = readStdreader .GetString(3);        
    mc.StdAddedDate = readStdreader .GetDate(1);        
    mc.StdAddedDate = readStdreader .GetDateTime(2);        
    StdList.Add(mc);    
 } 

 MessageBox.Show(StdList[0].StdDetails.ToString());
```